# Springboot get api taking too long time while multiple hits at a time

Tags: java, postgresql, response-time, parallel-execution

We have a springboot rest api get method which call downstream database. we use jdbc template queryforrowset method to get result set and map to object using while loop.

When we give single hit to the endpoint we are getting response in 25-30sec. But we hit it multiple times parallely the response time is increased to 2-3min.

We use controller bean scope prototype and all other bean scopes(service classes and dao classes) are singleton.
How can we decrease the response time when we have multiple hits parallely?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use on the main class the annotation:

```
@EnableAsync
```

And on the service use the:

```
@ASync
```

For more info:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async